# How to get full type name from the short name and vice-versa?

Tags: powershell

If I have the short name of an object type (eg: PSCredential, String, etc) I need to get the full type name (eg: System.Management.Automation.PSCredential, System.String, etc), and vice-versa.

I would think this would be as easy as using `Get-TypeData`, but for some weird reason that command returns info for types like PSCredential and ServiceController, but nothing for basic types like String, Int32, Boolean, etc.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the fully qualified name of a type by calling the type's [`.FullName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.fullname?view=net-7.0#system-type-fullname), i.e.:

```bash
[pscredential].FullName # => System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
```

From the fully qualified name to the [`.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.name?view=net-7.0#system-reflection-memberinfo-name) you can cast the string as [`[type]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-7.0):

```bash
([type] 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential').Name # => PSCredential
```

If you want to see their [*accelerator name*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_accelerators?view=powershell-7.3) i.e.: `bool` instead of `Boolean` (assuming they have one) you can use the following:

```
$accelerators = @{}
[PowerShell].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')::Get.GetEnumerator() |
    ForEach-Object { $accelerators[$_.Value.FullName] = $_.Key }
```

Then you can do:

```
$accelerators['System.Boolean'] # => bool
```

The above might certainly fail in some cases, as noted by OP in comments, while trying `[type] 'Process'`, the following should work in such cases:

```
$map = @{}
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |
    ForEach-Object { try { $_.GetExportedTypes() } catch { } } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $map[$_.Name] = $_.FullName
        $map[$_.FullName] = $_.Name
    }

$map['Process'] # => System.Diagnostics.Process
$map['System.Diagnostics.Process'] # => 'Process'
```

Comment: Thanks! The first one won't work since the value is a string but your second one works both ways so that's good enough.

Comment: @jerdub1993 happy to help. so if you have the name as string you can follow the same method (casting `type`) -> `([type] 'pscredential').FullName`

Comment: I ran into an issue with System.Diagnostics.Process, this one throws an error when trying to convert to a type: `[type]'process'`:
"Cannot convert the "Process" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type"."
Any ideas?

Comment: @jerdub1993 see my update. That should work